# Random EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a place that it cannot happen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I'm receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS at random times in a place that I confirmed the exception should not happen.
The line its happening on is

```
`[[LevelEditorScene sharedLevelEditor] setObject:object forKey:key]`
```

`LevelEditorScene` is a class, `setObject:forKey:` is a method I implemented (not the one from `NSObject`)
In GDB:

```
(gdb) print-object [LevelEditorScene sharedLevelEditor]
<LevelEditorScene = 06C3FF40 | Tag = -1>
```

Means `LevelEditorScene sharedLevelEditor` is ok.

```
(gdb) print (bool)[[LevelEditorScene sharedLevelEditor]
                    respondsToSelector:@selector(setObject:forKey:)]
$9 = true
```

Means it responds to the selector

```
(gdb) print-object object
15
(gdb) print-object key
Maze Width
```

Means the arguments are ok (it shouldn't matter anyway).
What else can be causing the exception?

Comment: what are the state of your key and object when you hit this line ?

BTW you can use po instead of print-object and p instead of print

Comment: well, are these values ok and not released?

Comment: actually, i cam see them in your answer. if you are using xCode 4 why not run your app against profiler and use the zombies instrument. When you hit a zombie profiler will stop with a small modal pop-up. In the pop up click the small arrow and it will take you to a view of allocs and releases for the problem object, if you look in there you can see where any problem object was alloced or released, any issue in your code you will be able to see

Comment: @Matt: Yes you can use `po` and `p` but in the context of posting a question here, the full command name makes it more understandable for those of us who rarely use the command line interface to the debugger.

Comment: @Dani:  I think it would be helpful if you posted the stack trace that gets emitted for the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Can we see your implementation of setObject:forKey: ?

Comment: @deanWombourne: what does it matter? it happens before the call

Comment: Your code in the question is pretty much perfect therefore it's time to look further out - how do you know your implementation of `setObject:forKey:` isn't both crashing and corrupting the stack so XCode can't tell you exactly where the crash is occurring? You also don't know how the compiler has optimised your code. If you're so certain that `setObject:forKey` isn't the culprit, set a breakpoint in there and see what happens.

Comment: @deanWombourne: these crashes are totally random and occur only at about 1% of the runs and these runs have nothing in common. I can't set a breakpoint for that.

Comment: Do you have more than one thread running in your app - this is starting to sound like some sort of race condition/threading problem?

Comment: @deanWombourne: not that I know of, nothing I done at least. I'm using cocos2d, maybe it does problems?

Comment: have you tried using the zombies instrument? it will tell you exactly what object is Zombied

Comment: @Matt, this is so random I can't reproduce it to try in zombies instrument.

Comment: @Dani - you need to add more code to your question - everything currently in your question is fine.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I found the problem. A loop inside `setObject:forKey:` was getting crazy and running way too much than it should and overflew every buffer I had in there.

Comment: it might help to edit your answer with a description of how you actually found out what was causing your issue. EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors are probably the most painful errors in an iPhone application so any advice you can give on how you isolated your problem might be useful to someone else. I'm pleased you resolved your issue!

Answer (score 2):

The line of code that your app crashes on might not be the cause of the problem. Most likely your method call is fine. Otherwise you'd receive a "message sent to unrecognised selector" error.

The best steps are to run the Analyzer. Failing that Profile using Leaks in Instruments.

A brilliant description on EXC_BAD_ACCESS, what causes it, and how to debug it can be found here:

[Lou Franco's Understanding EXC_BAD_ACCESS](http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html)

Comment: You are way too late. FYI, its was because of stack corruption.

Comment: Please if you could post the solution and mark that as the answer.